# Re-initialization an object provided by Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I have an interface called LoginService which is used with Retrofit. There was no accessToken before the user login. When the user has logged in, the LoginService Instance should be updated with acessToken so that the user could log out from the app. The problem is that LoginService class is not updated even though it is not declared as @Singleton. If the user has closed the app and reopen it again, the LoginService got updated and therefore he could log out of the app. How can I reinitialize the LoginService instance as soon as the accessToken has been updated?

Comment: I had the exact same problem I just removed the Singleton annotation and worked for me, can you post your code, maybe something else is causing this

Comment: I have removed the @Singleton annotation too. But still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

The key here is not the reinitialize the instance but to create a separate service whenever the user logs in.

you need to have two different interfaces one for API's pre-login and other for post login.

So one would be `Authapi.kt` and the other would be `Api.kt`

So first we need to create OkHttpBuilder for each service,

```
 @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(NetModule.NO_AUTH_CLIENT)
    fun provideNoAuthOkHttpClient(
            okHttpClientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder
    ): OkHttpClient {
        return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(NetModule.AUTH_CLIENT)
    fun provideAuthOkHttpClient(
            okHttpClientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder,
            tokenInterceptor: NetworkInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {
        return okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor).build()
    }
```

Network Interceptor is the class where you update your access token for API.

**NetworkInterceptor.kt**

```
class NetworkInterceptor @Inject constructor(
        val context: Context,
        serverBaseUrl: String,
        val moshi: Moshi,
        val preferences: PreferenceUtility

) : Interceptor {


    private fun Request.Builder.setDefaultHeaders(): Request.Builder {
        addHeader("App_version_code", BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE.toString())
        addHeader("App_version_name", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
        addHeader("Mobile_model", Build.MODEL.toString())
        addHeader("OS_version", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.toString())
        addHeader("OS_version_release", Build.VERSION.RELEASE.toString())
        if (preferences.customerId != -1L)
            addHeader("Client_id", preferences.customerId.toString())
        return this
    }

    private fun makeRequestWithAuthTokenAndTimeStamp(request: Request) = request.newBuilder()
            .setDefaultHeaders()
            .apply {
                val oldHeader = request.header("Authorization")
                if (oldHeader.isNullOrBlank()) {
                    val token = if (preferences.authToken.isBlank() || !preferences.customerAuthenticated) BuildConfig.ANONYMOUS_TOKEN else preferences.authToken
                    addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
                }
            }
            .url(request.url())
            .method(request.method(), request.body())
            .build()

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
         // ADD THE TOKEN'S OVER HERE
        var response = 
           chain.proceed(makeRequestWithAuthTokenAndTimeStamp(request))
         //You can also add refersh logic here.
        return response
    }

}
```

And you NetworkModule.kt will be

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(NetModule.NO_AUTH_CLIENT)
    fun provideNoAuthInterceptorRetrofit(
            moshi: Moshi,
            @Named(NetModule.NO_AUTH_CLIENT) okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
            debugPreferenceUtility: DebugPreferenceUtility
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(debugPreferenceUtility.serverBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(NetModule.AUTH_CLIENT)
    fun provideAuthInterceptorRetrofit(
            moshi: Moshi,
            @Named(NetModule.AUTH_CLIENT) okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
            debugPreferenceUtility: DebugPreferenceUtility
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(debugPreferenceUtility.serverBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApi(@Named(AUTH_CLIENT) retrofit: Retrofit) = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)



    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthApi(@Named(NO_AUTH_CLIENT) retrofit: Retrofit) = retrofit.create(AuthApi::class.java)
```

So the API's that will be used pre-login will be placed inside `AuthApi.kt` 
like send OTP etc and all the rest API will be placed inside `Api.kt` and Network Interceptor will take care of adding token.

Comment: I tried this before. But both AuthApi and Api objects are injected at the same time so the result is the same.

Comment: So what I can understand from it that you need to do some type of custom scoping, you can follow this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jccDA8Dy5DM&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8AOAspC3DHoBNZIBHbIOsC&index=36) for more detail in scoping